# Sending Calendar Events (Invitations) using iCal4j library (Java - Spring)

Tags: java, spring, calendar, google-calendar-api, ical4j

This question is relating to iCal4j library integration with a Java (Spring) application.

**Use case** -
In my application, when a user creates an event from the UI, the invitees should receive a calendar invitation, which they can add to their personal calendar (Google calendar, Outlook calendar or even Thundarbird calendar) by simply clicking on the event. Also, the event organizer should receive a calendar invitation of the same event.

**Concern** - 
While attendees receive the calendar invitation to the created event in the correct format (Google Calendar, Outlook and Thundarbird) via an email, the organizer receives an empty email with an attachment (invite.ics). Please note that this concern only raises in Gmail mail and Outlook mail clients. In Thunderbird, even the organizer receives a complete event request.
(Please refer the attached code snippet and images for further clarification).

Please let me know how to resolve this issue or any alternate libraries or solutions I can use to get this done.

Thanks in advance.

```
StringBuffer buffer = sb.append( "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\n" +
     "PRODID:-//PROD_NAME//PROD_ORG//EN\n" +
     "VERSION:2.0\n" +
     "X-WR-RELCALID:"+calendarEmail.getxWrRelcalid()+"\n" +
     "METHOD:REQUEST\n" +
     "BEGIN:VEVENT\n" +
     calendarEmail.getAttendeeString() +
     calendarEmail.getOrganizerString() +
     "DTSTART:" + calendarEmail.getDtStart() + "\n" +
     calendarEmail.getRruleString() +
     "DTEND:" + calendarEmail.getDtEnd() + "\n" +
     "LOCATION:" + calendarEmail.getLocation() + "\n" +
     "TRANSP:OPAQUE\n" +
     "SEQUENCE:"+calendarEmail.getSequence()+"\n" +
     "UID:" + calendarEmail.getUid() + "\n" +
     "DTSTAMP:" + calendarEmail.getDtStamp() + "\n" +
     "STATUS:"+calendarEmail.getEventStatusString()+"\n" +
     "CATEGORIES:" + calendarEmail.getCategory() + "\n" +
     "DESCRIPTION:" + calendarEmail.getDescription() + "\n" +
     "SUMMARY:" + calendarEmail.getSummary() + "\n" +
     "PRIORITY:5\n" +
     "CLASS:" + calendarEmail.getPublicity() + "\n" +
     "BEGIN:VALARM\n" +
     "TRIGGER:" + calendarEmail.getAlarmTrigger() + "\n" +
     "ACTION:" + calendarEmail.getAlarmAction() + "\n" +
     "DESCRIPTION:Reminder\n" +
     "END:VALARM\n" +
     "END:VEVENT\n" +
     "END:VCALENDAR" );
```

[image: Email received by the organizer who is using the Thunderbird mail client]

[image: Email received by the organizer who is using the Google mail client]

[image: Email received by an invitee who is using the Google mail client]

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more a question of how the iCalendar specification works. Specifically you may want to look at:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5546#section-3.2.2

In your case your program is acting on behalf of the Organizer, so I'm not sure you can send a "REQUEST" to the Organizer user.

You probably need to send a "PUBLISH" method to the Organizer user:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5546#section-3.2.1

You may also want to consider the SENT-BY parameter on your Organizer property to indicate the Organizer user didn't send the request (unless you want REPLYs to go back to your program):

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.2.18